# Unable to identify syntax error

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
session_start();
$customername =$_post["customername"];
$hobby = $_post["hobby"]
$_SESSION["customername"]="$customername";
$_SESSION["hobby"]="$hobby";

$target = "task11.php";
$link = "task11a.php";
echo link($target,$link);
?>
```

My objective is to retrieve information from a website and assign session variables, but I am getting a syntax error on the session variables. I also have to make a link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Help us help you - please share the faulty code and the text of the error you're getting.

Comment: Missing `;` after `$_post["hobby"]`. NEXT!

Comment: <?php
 
 session_start();
 $customername =$_post["customername"];
 $hobby = $_post["hobby"]
 $_SESSION["customername"]="$customername";
 $_SESSION["hobby"]="$hobby";

  $target = "task11.php";
  $link = "task11a.php";
  echo link($target,$link);
?>

Comment: superglobal variables are always in uppercase. so `$_POST`, not `$_post`

Comment: i fixed the missing ; and $_POST but now its showing undefined index on the variables and at the end bad file descriptor

Comment: @ImtiazKhandaker Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Superglobal variables are always in uppercase, so `$_post` should be `$_POST`. You are also defining your sessions incorrectly.

Change your code from

```
session_start();
$customername =$_post["customername"];
$hobby = $_post["hobby"]
$_SESSION["customername"]="$customername";
$_SESSION["hobby"]="$hobby";
```

To

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["customername"] = $_POST["customername"];
$_SESSION["hobby"] = $_POST["hobby"];
```

Comment: Hey! thanks i did but its still showing undefined index on both the variables

Comment: Is the full error `undefined index`? Can you show us where you define the sessions? What's their value?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: customername in I:\twa\twa***\practicals\prac2\Task11.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined index: hobby in I:\twa\twa137\practicals\prac2\Task11.php on line 5 Warning: link(): Bad file descriptor in I:\twa\twa***\practicals\prac2\Task11.php on line 11 

here's the full error message

Comment: @ImtiazKhandaker Can you show where you define the sessions?

Comment: their values are user input in a  html document and this php file is the action

Comment: i defined the session at the begining 

<?php
 
 session_start();
 $customername =$_POST["customername"];
 $hobby = $_POST["hobby"];
 $customername = $_SESSION["customername"];
 $hobby = $_SESSION["hobby"];

  $target = "task11.php";
  $link = "task11a.php";
  echo link($target,$link);
?>